# Execute Apex code periodically or triggers dependent on time?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am building a time records app that records time spent in projects by our users.

No we have to develop a feature to check if a certain person is getting close to the maximum time for a specific project so that Salesforce can inform the project manager.

At first I was thinknig of pooling that info from an external information but... If there is a way to execute a certain task every hour in salesforce then that would probably be the best solution.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scheduled Apex is the tool you're looking for. Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
global with sharing class YourScheduleClass implements Schedulable
{
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0-23 * * ?';

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) 
    {
        // Usually best to call another class from here rather than implementing
        // logic directly in the schedule class
    }

    // Just to show how it's called...
    static testMethod void testExecute()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        String tmpId = System.schedule('ScheduleTest', YourScheduleClass.CRON_EXP, new YourScheduleClass());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [scheduled apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm)